# Error - Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$call = "CALL spuser( ?,  ?,?,)" ;
$stmt = $connection2->prepare($call);
if ( !$stmt ) {
   die('prepare failed');
}
if ( !$stmt->bind_param('ssssssss',$_POST['name'],$_POST['lname'],$_POST['address']) ) {
   // $stmt->error has more info
   die('bind failed');
}
if ( !$stmt->execute() ) {
   // $stmt->error has more info
   die('execute failed');
}

$stmt->close();
```

Stored Procedure is:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spuser`(

IN id bigint, IN name varchar(25), IN lname varchar(25), IN address varchar(25), IN phoneno varchar(10), IN city varchar(10) )
BEGIN

Insert INTO user( name, lname, address, phoneno, city ) values (name, lname, address, phoneno, city) ;

END
```

As my project requirement I have to take 5 fields as IN parameter in stored procedure but when at the time of call procedure I have to use only 3 other fields for future.

Comment: Can you please format your question.?

Comment: there are argument mismatch between bind_params() & spuser().

Comment: 1. spuser() - mismatch in the number of parameters while declaration and calling.

Comment: 2. bind_params - there is a mismatch here as well with the number if params provided to bind.

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors.
1) `$call = "CALL spuser( ?,  ?,?,)";` requires exactly three parameters but you are passing 4: `$stmt->bind_param('ssssssss',$_POST['name'],$_POST['lname'],$_POST['address'])`.

2) You're stored procedure expects 5 parameters so you need to pass 5 parameters. If you don't know the values yet, pass either null or create another stored procedure.
See this question for optional parameters for stored procedures: [Writing optional parameters within stored procedures in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652241/)